# Bad aggregate when adding extra items to select wikidata sparql

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am looking to retrieve data for a given location.

So using the below I am able to retrieve the bordering locations of France and Scotland.

```
SELECT (GROUP_CONCAT(?borderLabel;separator=",") AS ?borders)
WHERE {
  ?location wdt:P47 ?border.
  ?location wdt:P2046 ?area.
  ?location wdt:P1082 ?population.
  FILTER (?location=wd:Q142 || ?location=wd:Q22)
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
    ?border rdfs:label ?borderLabel
  }
}
GROUP BY ?location
```

But as soon as I add anything to the SELECT, ie. `SELECT ?locationLabel (GROUP_CONCAT(?borderLabel;separator=",") AS ?borders)` it tells me `Query is malformed: Bad aggregate`

I am however able to add ?location to return the wd entity value without issue.

What is wrong here?

Comment: you have to group by any variable not used in an aggregate function.

Comment: but, and asked several times here, the ?locationLabel comes from a special non-standard feature of Blazegraph triple store

Comment: `SELECT ?locationLabel (GROUP_CONCAT(?borderLabel;separator=",") AS ?borders)
WHERE {
  ?location wdt:P47 ?border.
   ?border rdfs:label ?borderLabel. filter(langmatches(lang(?borderLabel), "en"))
         
  ?location wdt:P2046 ?area.
  ?location wdt:P1082 ?population.
  FILTER (?location=wd:Q142 || ?location=wd:Q22)
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".    
  }
  
   }

GROUP BY ?locationLabel`

Comment: I don't understand. I am grouping by ?location, but I am aggregating border property. So it isn't grouped by my aggregate?

Comment: For each group you have to define what happens to the other variables that you select. E.g. if you just do ` ... group by ?location` but do `select ?location ?locationLabel ...` what should be done with the values of `?locationLabel` given that there is exactly one group per `?location` value? that means, either you further refine the groups by appending it like `group by ?location ?locationLabel` or you do some aggregate on the values of `?locationLabel` e.g. `sample` or `group_concat`

Comment: OK. You shall have to excuse me as I am very new to SPARQL. I have come up with the above based on a few hours researching similar queries on here and tweaking to suit! I have tried your example, however this is listing every bordering location 3 times. I tried adding DISTINCT as I have seen this in a few queries on my travels, but this did not solve the issue. I added ?population in to the SELECT, and added it to the GROUP BY as well. This works - but if two populations for two locations were a match, would this not group them together, or not?

Comment: Taking your GROUP BY advice, I have come up with this. `SELECT ?locationLabel ?area ?population (GROUP_CONCAT(?borderLabel;separator=",") AS ?borders)
WHERE {
  ?location wdt:P47 ?border.
  ?location wdt:P2046 ?area.
  ?location wdt:P1082 ?population.
  FILTER (?location=wd:Q142 || ?location=wd:Q22)
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
    ?border rdfs:label ?borderLabel.
    ?location rdfs:label ?locationLabel
  }
}
GROUP BY ?location ?area ?population ?locationLabel`

Comment: You could also use `(SAMPLE(?area) AS ?s_area)` etc.

Comment: Anyway, you could post your comment as an answer.